# Sass :first-child compile error

Tags: css, sass

I'm new to Sass and I can't figure what is wrong with my code. Here I'm trying to get the first-child of class ".col-3" a margin-top of 0 px, but it doesn't compile and it's giving me an error. Here is my code, am I doing something wrong?
In Prepros I'm getting error 'invalid property name on line 35', which is 'margin-top: 30px' line.

```
@media (max-width: 620px)
    body
        .wrapper
            section
                .col-3
                    .col-1
                        width: 100%
                        margin-top: 30px
                    &:first-child
                        margin-top: 0px
```

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce this on [Sassmeister](http://sassmeister.com/).  If you can, I'll reopen it.  I get errors using the LibSass version, but not the Ruby Sass version (check the control panel), and it's not the same error you're reporting.  Otherwise, you'll need to submit a bug report to the Prepros people.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a space after the : or it wont compile. eg, width: 100% not width:100%